# Maximal ideal in commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain, $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal in $R[x]$ is of the form $\mathfrak{m} = (\mathfrak{p},f(x))$ where $\mathfrak{p}$ is a maximal ideal in $R$, and $f$ is a polynomial in $R[x]$ which is irreducible in $(R/\mathfrak{p})[x]$. Let $g(x) \in \mathfrak{m}$. 
I am know that exist a ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ in $R$ such that $(\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{a}) = 1 $, i.e $\mathfrak{p} + \mathfrak{a} = R$ and $\mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{a} = \mathfrak{p}\cap \mathfrak{a} = (p)$. (chapter 16, corollary 19, page 768, Abstract Algebra, Dummit Foote...)

Easily, since $g(x)\in \mathfrak{m}$, we have $ g(x) = l(x) + f(x).k(x)$ where $l(x) \in \mathfrak{p}[x]$.
The questions is: Can we make a "strong" form as to
show that there exists an ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ in $R$ such that $g$ can be show as the form
$$ag(x) = p h(x) + a f(x) k(x)$$
where $p\in \mathfrak{p}$ such that $(p) = \mathfrak{p} \mathfrak{a}$, $(\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{a}) = 1$ and $a\in \mathfrak{a} - \mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Is this problem from a book?

Comment: Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain, sorry you I have a mistake